# maven dependency conflict java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory error when creating aws S3 client

Tags: java, apache, ssl, amazon-s3

I am getting the below error when I am trying to create amazon S3 client. It worked earlier and after I have done few code changed from then on I am seeing this error. I feel it could be of some dependency conflict but unable to find it out. Try many things but nothing could help.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:91)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:51)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:39)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:301)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:164)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:523)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:503)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:485)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:457)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:439)
        at com.ge.hc.cloud.e2e.workflows.steps.BasicWorkflowSteps.<clinit>(BasicWorkflowSteps.java:72)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:386)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.webEnabledStepLibrary(StepFactory.java:201)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.createProxyStepLibrary(StepFactory.java:164)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.instantiateNewStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:117)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.instantiateNewStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:109)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.getNewStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:77)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.getStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:72)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepAnnotations.instantiateAnyUnitiaializedSteps(StepAnnotations.java:52)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepAnnotations.instanciateScenarioStepFields(StepAnnotations.java:41)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepAnnotations.injectScenarioStepsInto(StepAnnotations.java:23)
        at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStepFactory.createInstanceOfType(SerenityStepFactory.java:80)
        at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator.stepsInstance(StepCreator.java:83)
        at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCreator$ParametrisedStep.perform(StepCreator.java:595)
        at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner$FineSoFar.run(StoryRunner.java:566)
```

Appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Did you add any jars recently? That could have same package name + class name? Maybe wrong class is being loaded after those jars?

Comment: you can run `mvn dependency:analyze` and check the report to make sure you have the http client jar in path

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. I was using AWS JavaV2 SDK `software.amazon.awssdk`  with version `2.19.14`.
The Amazon Java SDK jar that I had imported had a dependency on `org.apache.httpcomponents`. Once I imported the dependency and built the project again, I was able to create the client.

My pom.xml looked something like this.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```